# Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'INTERSECT(SELECT friend_id FROM user_friend_list WHERE user_id = '20' and frien' at line 3

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
(SELECT friend_id FROM user_friend_list WHERE user_id = '13' and 
`friend_id` in(select user_id from user_friend_list where friend_id='13' and `is_delete` = 'No') 
and is_delete = 'No')INTERSECT(SELECT friend_id FROM user_friend_list WHERE user_id = '20' and
friend_id in(select user_id from user_friend_list where friend_id='20' and is_delete = 'No') 
and is_delete = 'No');
```

Comment: There is no `INTERSECT` in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

No INTERSECT operator exists in MySQL.
try with INNER JOIN instead:

```
SELECT friend_id FROM
 (SELECT friend_id ...) T1
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT friend_id ... ) T2 
ON T1.friend_id = T2.friend_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support the INTERSECT operator. However, you can simulate the INTERSECT operator.

Here there's a how-to guide to simulate INTERSECT in MYSQL:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-intersect/